# C# Unable to cast object

Tags: c#, linq

I used linq to group my data by `TradingDate`. The line `statuses.TradingDate.ToString();` is resulting in error

`InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'FileInsight.Models.RelatedStatuses' to type 'System.String'.`

I am not casting RelatedStatuses object to a string I am casting a DateTime property within the object to a string. I have added the Model and Method below

**Method with casting error**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, RelatedStatuses>>> GetFilterFileAndRelatedFiles(string searchString)
{
    List<FilterFileAndRelatedFiles> filterFileRelatedFilesList = new List<FilterFileAndRelatedFiles>();
    IEnumerable<FilterFileAndRelatedFiles> filterFileRelatedFiles = await _tradeLogDBContext.GetFilterFileAndRelatedFiles(searchString);

    List<RelatedStatuses> relatedStatuses = new List<RelatedStatuses>();
    foreach(FilterFileAndRelatedFiles ff in filterFileRelatedFiles)
    {
        // Calculates Statuses
        bool DEStatus = ff.DEFileIsValid && (ff.DEFileImportStatus.Equals("SUCCESS"));
        bool VmondagStatus = ff.VmonDagFileExDaStatus.Equals("SUCCESS") && ff.VMonDagFileImportStatus.Equals("SUCCESS") && ff.VMonDagFileParseStatus.Equals("SUCCESS");
        bool ProductXMLStatus = ff.ProductXmlFileImportStatus != null && ff.ProductXmlFileImportStatus.Equals("SUCCESS");
        bool FFStatus = ff.FilterFileImportStatus.Equals("SUCCESS");
        bool DeepDiveStatus = ff.DeepDiveFileImportStatus != null && ff.DeepDiveFileImportStatus.Equals("SUCCESS");
        bool VappFamilyStatus = ff.VAppFamilyXmlFileImportStatus.Equals("SUCCESS");
        bool PlStatus = ff.TradingEventPLFileStatusStatus.Equals("Approved");
        // Created Related Status Object
        var relatedStatus = new RelatedStatuses(ff.filterFileName, DEStatus, VmondagStatus, ProductXMLStatus, FFStatus, DeepDiveStatus, VappFamilyStatus, PlStatus, ff.tradingDate);
        // Add to list
        relatedStatuses.Add(relatedStatus);
    }
    var orderedByDate = from statuses in relatedStatuses
                        group statuses by statuses.TradingDate.ToString();
    return orderedByDate;
}
```

**Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FileInsight.Models
{
    public class RelatedStatuses
    {
        public RelatedStatuses(string name, bool DEStatus, bool VmonDagStatus, bool ProductXMLStatus, bool FFStatus, bool DeepDiveStatus, bool VappFamilyStatus, bool PLFileStatus, DateTime TradingDate)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.DEStatus = DEStatus;
            this.VmonDagStatus = VmonDagStatus;
            this.ProductXMLStatus = ProductXMLStatus;
            this.FFStatus = FFStatus;
            this.DeepDiveStatus = DeepDiveStatus;
            this.VappFamilyStatus = VappFamilyStatus;
            this.PLFileStatus = PLFileStatus;
            this.TradingDate = TradingDate;
        }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool DEStatus { get; set; }
        public bool VmonDagStatus { get; set; }
        public bool ProductXMLStatus { get; set; }
        public bool FFStatus { get; set; }
        public bool DeepDiveStatus { get; set; }
        public bool VappFamilyStatus { get; set; }
        public bool PLFileStatus { get; set; }
        public DateTime TradingDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Please narrow it down to the line(s) where the problem occur and get rid of the unnecessary code.

Comment: @Sach Thank you, I have reduced the code and pointed out where I think the issue is.

Comment: what is `_tradeLogDataService.GetFilterFileAndRelatedFiles(searchString)` doing? Also looks like your `searchString` is never populated.

Comment: @AntLaC I have added more information in the post. The search string can be empty it is just used to match a column name but if empty will match all in the column

Comment: I would be helpful to know exactly at where the error is being generated... basically what line in you code is actually throwing the error?

Comment: @tocsoft Thank you, I have used the debugger to isolate the exact line. it is `statuses.TradingDate.ToString();` in `GetFilterFileAndRelatedFiles(searchString)`

Comment: I that case you probably want to rework your question to highlight the fact that its not an asp.net-core issue but a general issue with what you've done in the Linq query.

Comment: I created a mock class of RelatedStatus and did the same LinqStatement as you, I am not getting the conversion error. I would suggest wrapping a try..catch and stepping through the code

Comment: Is the error encountered on your Visual Studio intellisense, on build, or on execution?

Comment: How are you using the result from function `GetFilterFileAndRelatedFiles(string searchString)`? Remember that you are returning a query that will be executed on first use, most likely on a for-each loop, where you are trying to convert it to a string.

Comment: @Markuzy The error is during execution

Comment: @Luis I am just calling it and returning the value in my controller like so
 `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, RelatedStatuses>> relatedStatuses = await _tradeLogDataService.GetFilterFileAndRelatedFiles(searchString);
            return relatedStatuses;`

Comment: Are you expecting to get an output like this: `[ { key: "2020-08-08", statuses: [ { name: "some-name", DEStatus: true ... }, ...] } ]`

Comment: @perpetualrag have you ever solved the problem? According to your code, I have created a sample on my side, [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fXKS.png) looks that it works well on my side. If the problem was solved, try to organize a solution and make it as answered, it can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. If still not working, please check the relatedStatuses item's values, perhaps the issue is related date value.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT Thank you, I took a weekend off because I was frustrated. The answer below seems to solve it but not sure if it's the best. I will accept it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replicate the Exception running from an API controller and it appear that the parser (in my case JSON parser) is having a hard time handling `IGrouping`. I made a simple change projecting the `IGrouping` interface into a anonymous (`dynamic`) type which allowed me to return the list:

In the API Controller:

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
   [HttpGet]
   public async Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>> Get()
   {
      IEnumerable<dynamic> relatedStatuses = await GetFilterFileAndRelatedFiles();
      return relatedStatuses;
   }

   private async Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>> GetFilterFileAndRelatedFiles()
   {
      var time1 = DateTime.UtcNow;
      var time2 = time1.AddDays(3);
      var data = new List<RelatedStatuses>() {
         new RelatedStatuses("1", true, true, true, true, true, true, true, time2),
         new RelatedStatuses("2", true, true, true, true, true, true, true, time2),
         new RelatedStatuses("3", true, true, true, true, true, true, true, time1),
         new RelatedStatuses("4", true, true, true, true, true, true, true, time1),
         new RelatedStatuses("5", true, true, true, true, true, true, true, time2),
         new RelatedStatuses("6", true, true, true, true, true, true, true, time2),
         new RelatedStatuses("7", true, true, true, true, true, true, true, time1),
      };
      return await Task.FromResult(
         (from obj in data
            group obj by obj.TradingDate.ToString()).ToList().Select(statusGroup =>
            {
               /*
               * Projecting the IGrouping interface structure in to an anonymous object...
               */
               return new { key = statusGroup.Key, statuses = statusGroup.Select(status => status).ToList() };
            })
      );
   }
}
```

Sample output:

```
[
    {
        "key": "08/11/2020 04:34:59",
        "statuses": [
            {
                "name": "1",
                "deStatus": true,
                "vmonDagStatus": true,
                "productXMLStatus": true,
                "ffStatus": true,
                "deepDiveStatus": true,
                "vappFamilyStatus": true,
                "plFileStatus": true,
                "tradingDate": "2020-08-11T04:34:59.3080946Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "2",
                "deStatus": true,
                "vmonDagStatus": true,
                "productXMLStatus": true,
                "ffStatus": true,
                "deepDiveStatus": true,
                "vappFamilyStatus": true,
                "plFileStatus": true,
                "tradingDate": "2020-08-11T04:34:59.3080946Z"
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "08/08/2020 04:34:59",
        "statuses": [
            {
                "name": "3",
                "deStatus": true,
                "vmonDagStatus": true,
                "productXMLStatus": true,
                "ffStatus": true,
                "deepDiveStatus": true,
                "vappFamilyStatus": true,
                "plFileStatus": true,
                "tradingDate": "2020-08-08T04:34:59.3080946Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "4",
                "deStatus": true,
                "vmonDagStatus": true,
                "productXMLStatus": true,
                "ffStatus": true,
                "deepDiveStatus": true,
                "vappFamilyStatus": true,
                "plFileStatus": true,
                "tradingDate": "2020-08-08T04:34:59.3080946Z"
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best practice but it works so thank you!

Comment: If you find a better way, just add it as an answer and mark it as the solution so that others can also benefit from it. :)